# Workflow Email not Sending

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, email

I created a workflow in SPD13 to send a reminder email until task result is changed to "closed".  The workflow starts and the notification date is determined by the workflow.  However, the workflow will not send the reminder email, but I have called for the email to be sent.  Please see the workflow below.

> Below are the workflow steps, what could be wrong?

```
If current item:Result equals open

and Variable: Default Date equals 1/1/1900

and Current item: Notification Date equals Variable:DefaultDate

Add -2 days to Current item:Due Date (Output to Variable:DueDate)

Email Current Item: Requester 

then Update item in Current item 

then Pause until Current item: Notification Date


If Current item:Result equals Open

Email Current item: Requester

then Add 2 days to Current item: Notification Date (Output to Variable:DueDate)

then Update item in Current item

then Pause until Current item: Notification Date
```

Comment: Are you trying to send email to internal or external user?

Comment: @Roman Internal users

Answer (score 1):

Can you try modify step "then Update item in Current item " to "set field in current item" 
Update should be used to modify items other than current item. 
Then try to check the workflow.